# Need help understanding difference between Get-Content and Import-Csv in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm having trouble understanding when to use Get-Content and when to use Import-Csv for modifying a CSV file. Here is an example of my file, which is an output of a hash table:

```
Name            Key           Value  
AOI1\\ABC1      AOI1\\ABC1     TRUE 
AOI2\\DEF2      AOI2\\DEF2     TRUE
\#AOI3\#\\GHI3  \#AOI3\#\\GHI3 FALSE
```

I need to do the following to the file:

1. Remove '\\' and everything after it in the Name column
2. Remove '\\' and everything before it in the Key column
3. Replace '\#' with '#' in the last row
4. Rename the column headers

The result should look like this:

```
Loc     FName  Result  
AOI1    ABC1   TRUE 
AOI2    DEF2   TRUE
#AOI3#  GHI3   FALSE
```

For removing the '\\' and everything after in the Name column, I came up with this script:

```
Import-Csv c:\test.csv | 
    % {$_.Name.split('\\\\')[0]}
```

This outputs the following:

```
AOI1  
AOI2
```

However, I want to be able to write everything back to the same Csv file, so I tried changing it to:

```
Get-Content c:\test.csv | 
    % {$_.Name.split('\\\\')[0]}
```

However, I ended up with a "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression" error message. If I keep the Import-Csv and modify the script to also do item 4, I get the same error message. Here's that script:

```
Import-Csv U:\To_Delete\Layer_search\results_STACK_layers.csv |
    Select-Object @{n='AOI';e={$_.'Name'}}, @{n='LAYER';e={$_.'Key'}}, @{n='IN MAP';e={$_.'Value'}} |
    % {$_.Name.split('\\\\')[0]}
```

So, how do I modify my CSV and output it to the same CSV afterwards? What could be causing that error message?

Sorry for the long-winded post, but I wanted to provide enough examples.

Thanks!

Comment: `Get-Content` returns an array of lines of text. `Import-CSV` returns and array of objects where the CSV column headers are the property names of the objects & each subsequent row is a new object. so your `Get-Content c:\test.csv` example is trying to address the `.Name` property of a line of text ... and there is no such thing. [*grin*]

Comment: In addition to Lee_Daily's comments, where does your original output come from? If it's output from PowerShell, I would recommend not to use a textual output format (such as that produced by `Format-Table` or `Format-List`) and use `Export-Csv` instead.

Comment: Original CSV comes from a PS script which uses an Export-CSV.

Comment: If you have a CSV to begin with, PowerShell can read it as a list of objects using `Import-Csv` (as Lee_Daily noted). What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

presuming you cannot use the advice from Bill_Stewart about fixing the source, here is one way to do the conversion. [*grin*] part of your problem was your use of the string split *method* instead of the string split *operator*. the 1st treats *every character* as a split target. the 2nd uses regex to split on the *split string* instead of on the characters in the split string.

```
# fake reading in a CSV file
#    in real life, use Import-CSV
$InStuff = @'
Name, Key, Value
AOI1\\ABC1, AOI1\\ABC1, TRUE
AOI2\\DEF2, AOI2\\DEF2, TRUE
\#AOI3\#\\GHI3, \#AOI3\#\\GHI3, FALSE
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$Results = foreach ($IS_Item in $InStuff)
    {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        # new version removes the unwanted "\" from the ends of the "Loc" value
        #Loc = ($IS_Item.Name -split [regex]::Escape('\\'))[0]
        Loc = ($IS_Item.Name -split [regex]::Escape('\\'))[0].Replace('\')
        FName = ($IS_Item.Key -split [regex]::Escape('\\'))[1]
        Result = [convert]::ToBoolean($IS_Item.Value)
        }
    }

# on screen
$Results

# send to a CSV file
$Results |
    Export-Csv -LiteralPath "$env:TEMP\Heather_RearrangedCSV.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

on screen ...

```
Loc      FName Result
---      ----- ------
AOI1     ABC1    True
AOI2     DEF2    True
#AOI3#   GHI3   False
```

CSV file content ...

```
"Loc","FName","Result"
"AOI1","ABC1","True"
"AOI2","DEF2","True"
"#AOI3#","GHI3","False"
```

Comment: Lee, this works well for what I need, so thank you! My only question is how do I also incorporate the replacement of '\#' with '#' in the Loc column? I tried adding it at the end of that line, but that didn't work.

Comment: I figured it out. Here is what worked for me: AOI = ($LItem.Name -split [regex]::Escape('\\'))[0] -replace '\\\#','#'. Thanks again for all of your help!

Comment: @Heather - glad that you got it! i edited my answer to add a version of the `Loc`" line that uses the `.Replace()` string method to do the same thing as your code. [*grin*]